# Manager has enough members for the project , but is relying completely on me and not assigning any work to the other person

Tags: ethics

We have a team of 7 people including two developers (including me), two business associates, two statistical analysits and the manager cum Solutions Architect (manager is also responsible for handling high level architecture). We are considering another person (please refer to [this question here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/193316/manager-wants-to-hire-an-additional-resource-with-experience-in-a-skill-that-i-d), which the manager has not hired yet.

Since the start of the project, the manager is relying on me for everything. Like every single thing. Even when there is another developer, the manager is not assigning any work. Even when some work is assigned to that another developer, the person is unable to do anything.

One example - the other developer told the manager that he has worked on Git. But, since I knew his attitude, I told him to re-visit some Git concepts, since he was going to ask me anyways, and we need to learn Git. He said to me that he has worked on Git in his previous company. However, the following day, he is asking me how to push the code to Repository. When I confronted him that he clearly told he could handle it, he said " There may be something new in this project for pushing the code to Repository". I ignored him, saying that there is nothing new and he can handle the task himself. This is just one example. He even wants me to send him search results for some codes that is new for both of us, even when I am assigned a different task.

I can help him, when I am free, but I am normally not free. And even if my manager knows this attitude of this person, he is neither firing him, nor hiring another associate.

Sometimes, I am free. Other times, I am totally packed, and on top of that , I need to handle this ridicolous non -professional team member. During those times, I feel burnt out so much.

Moreover, the manager wants to get things done as soon as possible, even if it means starting the day early, which is okay, if there is an emergency. But, even when there is no emergency, manager wants that done asap. So, let's say, if I start my day at 9 AM, manager wants me to login early at 8 AM and finish the task, whether there is any emergency of completing that task or not.

I am frustrated and sometimes, I get so burnt out and depressed with this behavior. What should I do ?

***Edit:-***

**Updating the question to avoid possible confusion :-**

1. The other developer is not under PIP. There is no consideration for that either
2. The project has enough budget to add at least 4 more people, apart from the 7 members now (includes the manager). Because, manager told me so.
3. Manager has already told me a few times (personally) that the developer is not catching upto speed. In addition, he has been scolding him sometimes, as he is unable to do, what he confidently told he could. What the manager does not know is that he (the other developer) puts his workload onto me. I don't want to rat out my fellow colleague, but he is getting on my nerves.

Comment: "The other developer is not under PIP." - How would you know? PIPs are supposed to be confidential.

Comment: Asking how you push is entirely reasonable; different companies use git in different ways.

Comment: @JoelEtherton In our company, when you are under PIP, you cannot be assigned to a project

Comment: @JackAidley I know, which is why I told that it is exactly the same as a normal git push. I even game him a few Tutorial videos

Answer (score 18):

> Even when some work is assigned to that another developer, the person is unable to do anything.

At the risk of stating the obvious: That's probably why your manager stopped assigning work to them.

> Manager has already told me a few times (personally) that the developer is not catching upto speed. In addition, he has been scolding him sometimes, as he is unable to do, what he confidently told he could.

Except for some very rare exceptions, managers can't turn a non-productive developer into a productive developer. They can remove non-productive developers and *try* to hire productive developers.

Sometimes, they can't even do that: Some people can't be fired for whatever reasons (which will not be discussed with you, and which are none of your business), and sometimes (such as right now) good developers are extremely hard to find on the job market.

What your manager *can* do is to get the non-productive developer off your back, if he is consuming your time without benefit. However, to do that, your manager needs to *know* about these problems. Which leads to the next point:

> What the manager does not know is that he (the other developer) puts his workload onto me. I don't want to rat out my fellow colleague, but he is getting on my nerves.

This is a mistake. Your manager's job is to enable you to do your work and to fix problems that prevent you from doing your work. You manager cannot read minds. If you hide problems from them, they cannot fix them.

Talk to your manager about both issues:

1. Helping your colleague is taking a considerable amount of your time. It seems like a waste of time to you, and you want to know whether you should continue doing that.
2. The workload is starting to affect your well-being. If you are truly the only productive developer in your team, you burning out and going on sick leave will be the last thing that your manager wants. Maybe priorities can be changed, maybe projects can be moved. But you won't know if you don't ask.

Comment: I’d like to add, that if you’re doing Scrum, your Retrospective would be the right place and time to discuss the colleague’s behaviour. Even if you don’t use Scrum, a shared feedback session once in a while would be mutually beneficial here.
Also: learn to say no to people. Or at least ask them to elaborate on their question and send it via email.

Answer (score 4):

A good manager will not discuss the performance of other team members with you.

It is possible the other employee is currently on a PIP (performance improvement plan) or that the manager is collecting evidence to put the employee on such a plan. If this is the case there isn't really much you can do other than provide facts to your manager to help them support the case that the other employee needs to improve their performance.

It is also possible that your team is "right sized" meaning that if both you and the other employee were contributing fully that you would have enough resources. In short your manager may not be able to hire additional staff instead they need to either coach the existing staff and/or replace them i.e. they can't hire until they have fired.

Answer (score 1):

So there are two developers you and a guy who will goof up anything he is assigned.

Given those parameters, I would prefer to do all the work myself.  It will save time as I will not have to redo the work or answer questions from the other developer.

You should do your best to minimize the work done on this project by the other developer.